# Which data structure might be a more efficient implementation?

Tags: c, bash, data-structures, hashtable

I was doing an exercise on reading from a setup file in which every line specifies two words and a number. The number denotes the number of words in between the two words specified. Another file – `input.txt` – has a block of text, and the program attempts to count the number of occurrences in the input file which follows the constraints in each line in the setup file (i.e., two particular words *a* and *b* should be separated by *n* words, where *a*, *b* and *n* are specified in the setup file.

So I've tried to do this as a shell script, but my implementation is probably highly inefficient. I used an array to store the words from the setup file, and then did a linear search on the text file to find out the words, and the works. Here's a bit of the code, if it helps:

```
#!/bin/sh

j=0
count=0;
m=0;
flag=0;
error=0;
while read line; do
    line=($line);
    a[j]=${line[0]}
    b[j]=${line[1]}
    num=${line[2]}
    c[j]=`expr $num + 0`
    j=`expr $j + 1`
done <input2.txt

while read line2; do
    line2=($line2)
    for (( i=0; $i<=50; i++ )); do
        for (( m=0; $m<j; m++)); do
            g=`expr $i + ${c[m]}`
            g=`expr $g + 1`
            if [ "${line2[i]}" == "${a[m]}" ] ; then
                for (( k=$i; $k<$g; k++)); do
                    if [[ "${line2[k]}" == *.* ]]; then
                        flag=1
                        break
                    fi
                done
                if [ "${b[m]}" == "${line2[g]}" ] ; then
                    if [ "$flag" == 1 ] ; then 
                        error=`expr $error + 1`
                    fi
                    count=`expr $count + 1`
                fi
                flag=0
            fi
            if [ "${line2[i]}" == "${b[m]}" ] ; then
                for (( k=$i; $k<$g; k++)); do
                    if [[ "${line2[k]}" == *.* ]]; then
                        flag=1
                        break
                    fi
                done
                if [ "${a[m]}" == "${line2[g]}" ] ; then
                    if [ "$flag" == 1 ] ; then 
                        error=`expr $error + 1`
                    fi              
                count=`expr $count + 1`
                fi
                flag=0
            fi
        done
    done 
done <input.txt

count=`expr $count - $error`

echo "| Count = $count |"
```

As you can see, this takes a lot of time.

I was thinking of a more efficient way to implement this, in C or C++, this time. What could be a possible alternative implementation of this, efficiency considered? I thought of hash tables, but could there be a better way?

I'd like to hear what everyone has to say on this.

Comment: Can you post some input file samples ?

Comment: Ok. Suppose the input file contains the sentence "Iterators are the mechanism that makes it possible to decouple algorithms from containers." The setup file contains a single line, "mechanism possible 3". The program would then return 1 since there's one occurrence of such a condition.

Comment: Are the pairs ordered? I.e. should "possible mechanism 3" also yield a match?

Comment: You use a number of Basisms in this script, so the shebang is wrong, and you might as well use the built-in arithmetic facilities of Bash rather than `expr`. I would do this in Awk, Python, or Perl, though, rather than either of Bash or C/C++.

Comment: @tripleee No they aren't ordered - it should work either way(possible mechanism 3 would yield the same result as mechanism possible 3)

Comment: @tripleee I suppose I could give it a shot in Perl/Python. How would you suggest I go about implementing it more efficiently?

Comment: Kudos for trying to implement this in Bash to begin with. It’s obviously completely crazy but it’s impressive at the same time.\

Comment: I would expect the same algorithm in a proper scripting language to run significantly faster. You may not need to do much rethinking or refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fully working possibility. It is not 100% pure `bash` since it uses (GNU) `sed`: I'm using `sed` to lowercase everything and to get rid of punctuation marks. Maybe you won't need this. Adapt to your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

input=input.txt
setup=setup.txt

# The Check function
Check() {
   # $1 is word1
   # $2 is word2
   # $3 is number of words between word1 and word2
   nb=0
   # Get all positions of w1
   IFS=, read -a q <<< "${positions[$1]}"
   # Check, for each position, if word2 is at distance $3 from word1
   for i in "${q[@]}"; do
      [[ ${words[$i+$3+1]} = $2 ]] && ((++nb))
   done
   echo "$nb"
}

# Slurp input file in an array
words=( $(sed 's/[,.:!?]//g;s/\(.*\)/\L\1/' -- "$input") )

# For each word, specify its positions in file
declare -A positions
pos=0
for i in "${words[@]}"; do
   positions[$i]+=$((pos++)),
done

# Do it!
while read w1 w2 p; do
   # Check that w1 w2 are not empty
   [[ -n $w2 ]] || continue
   # Check that p is a number
   [[ $p =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || continue
   n=$(Check "$w1" "$w2" "$p")
   [[ $w1 != $w2 ]] && (( n += $(Check "$w2" "$w1" "$p") ))
   echo "$w1 $w2 $p: $n"
done < <(sed 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' -- "$setup")
```

How does it work:

- we first read the whole file *input.txt* in the array `words`: a word per field. Observe I'm using `sed` here to delete all punctuation marks (well, only `,`, `.`, `:`, `!`, `?`, for testing purposes, add some more if you wish) and to lowercase every letter.
- Loop through the array `words` and for each word, put its position in an associative array `positions`:

  ```
  w => "position1,position2,...,positionk,"
  ```
- Finally, we read the *setup.txt* file (filtered through `sed` again to lowercase everything – optional see below). Do a quick check whether the line is valid (2 words and a number) and then call the `Check` function (twice, for each permutation of the given words, unless both words are equal).
- The `Check` function finds all positions of word1 in file, thanks to associative array `positions` and then using the array `words`, check whether word2 is at the given "distance" from word1.

*The second `sed` is optional.* I've filtered the *setup.txt* file through `sed` to lowercase everything. This `sed` will leave only very little overhead, so, efficiency-wise, it's not a big deal. You'll be able to add more filtering later to make sure the data is consistent with how the script will use it (e.g., get rid of punctuation marks). Otherwise you could:

- Get rid of it altogether: replace the corresponding line (the last line) with just

  ```
  done < "$setup"
  ```

  In this case, you'll have to trust the guy/gal who will write the *setup.txt* file.
- Get rid of it as above, but still want to convert everything to lowercase. In this case, below the

  ```
  while read w1 w2 p; do
  ```

  line, just add these lines:

  ```
  w1=${w1,,}
  w2=${w2,,}
  ```

  That's the bash way to lowercase a string.

*Caveats.* The script will break if:

- The number given in *setup.txt* file starts with a `0` and contains an `8` or a `9`. This is because bash will consider it's an octal number, where `8`'s and `9`'s are not valid. There are workarounds for this.
- The text in *input.txt* doesn't follow proper typographical practices: a punctuation mark is always followed by a space. E.g., if the input file contains

  ```
  The quick,brown,dog jumps over the lazy fox
  ```

  then after the `sed` treatment the text will look like

  ```
  The quickbrowndog jumps over the lazy fox
  ```

  and the words *quick*, *brown* and *dog* won't be treated properly. You can replace the `sed` substitution `s/[,:!?]//g` with `s/[,:!?]/ /g` to convert these symbols with a space. It's up to you, but in that case, abbreviations as, e.g., *e.g.* and *i.e.* might not be considered properly… it now really depends what you need to do.
- Different character encodings are used… I don't really know how robust you need the script to be, and what languages and encodings you'll consider.
- (Add stuff here `:)`.)

*About efficiency.* I'd say the algorithm is rather efficient. `bash` is probably not the best suited language for that, but it's a lot of fun, and not that difficult after all if we look at it (less than 20 lines of relevant code, and even less than that!). If you only have 50 files with 50000 words, it's ok, you will not notice too much difference between `bash` and `perl/python/awk/C/you-name-it`: `bash` performs decently quickly for files of this type. Now if you have 100000 files each containing millions of words, well, a different approach should be taken and a different language should be used (but I don't know which one).

Answer (score 1):

If:

- it can get complex for the sake of efficiency
- the text file can be large
- the setup file can have many rows

then I would do it the following way:

As preparation I would create:

1. A hash map with the index of the word as key and the word as the value (named -say- WORDS). So WORDS[1] would be the first word, WORDS[2] the second, and so on.
2. A hashmap with the words as keys and the list of indexes as values (named -say- INDEXES). So if WORDS[2] and WORDS[5] is "dog" and none other, than INDEXES["dog"] would yield the numers 2 and 5. The value can be a dynamic indexed array or a linked list. Linked list is better if there are words that occur many times.

You can read the text file, and populate both structures at the same time.

Processing:

For each row of the setup file I would get the indexes in INDEXES[firstword] and check if WORDS[index + wordsinbetween + 1] equals with secondword. If it does, that's a hit.

Notes:

Preparation: You only read the text file once. For each word in the text file, you're doing fast operations thats' performance is not really effected by the amount of words already processed.

Processing: You only read the setup file once. For each row you're here too doing operations that are only effected by the number of occurences of firstword in the text file.

Comment: That is an idea. Implementing INDEXES and WORDS as arrays would be the solution I suppose. But - call me dumb, but - how can an index of an array be a string? You say INDEXES["dog"] would yield the position of "dog" in the text.

Comment: Those are known as associative arrays, or (in Python) dictionaries, or (in Perl etc) hashes.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned "hash map" in my answer. :)